# Button''s on-click action doesn't work

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using `Custom Product preview` extension from AITOC.

After installing the extension, I have checked the product to edit.

After editing the product, I am clicking on `Apply changes` button to apply custom design, but button is not working

When I click on a Button, action hits but change after 1 second with domain name, which is showing `403 forbidden error`.

I have contacted to the support team & they replied that it is the server configuration issue.

So, is this issue related to the server configuration or anything else?

Comment: Please specify your issue in detail, what you have done so far?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya, I have updated my question

Comment: possibly nginx configuration issue, have you checked this? (i.e. is the url hitting/matching a forbidden rule)

Comment: I am using apache